# Loading sound from ftp server with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

im trying to load a sound and play from an ftp server from my kivy interface.

```
class DownPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(DownPopup,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    source = 'ftp://mcroni:paloma@ftp.goshen.heliohost.org/public_html/sermons/StoneBwoy-Candy.mp3'


def play(self):
    sound = SoundLoader.load(self.source)
    if sound:
        print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
        print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
        sound.play()
```

but i get this error

```
Sound found at ftp://mcr:pal@ftp.go.heliohost.org/public_html/ser/StoneBwoy-Candy.mp3
[ERROR             ] [AudioGstplayer] b'No URI handler implemented for "ftp".'
Sound is -1.000 seconds
```

and if i parse the url into urllib.request.urlopen(url) and i print the results out ,i get this

```
addinfourl at 116129688 whose fp = <addclosehook at 116072400 whose fp = <_io.BufferedReader name=1084
```

Comment: Try with http and see if that works. Then try http auth if you need it

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: It looks like SoundLoader does not handle non-local/web files. Download the manually and then pass a path to the file to SoundLoader.

Comment: i have found a way to make it work..i just had to keep the files in the public_html folder